# Displaying/Hiding table data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to organize all chapters and their respective topics from a book in a html table. If I add a `td` for each topic (from all 22 chapters) the table will get too long. I'd like to set a button inside every chapter's  `td`, so that I can display all topics in a `tr` below just by clicking it. 
I thought the code below would work fine, but it didn't. Any ideas? Thanks!

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");

function TogTop() {
 if (t1.classList.contains("show") == false) {
  t1.classList.add("show");
 } else {
  t1.classList.remove("show");
 }
}
```

```css
#t1 {
 display: none;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>[1] Data Communications, Data Networking, and the Internet <button onclick="TogTop()">Topics</button></td>
   <td>[2] Protocol Architecture, TCP/IP, and the Internet-Based Applications</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="t1">
   <td colspan="2">
    <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
    </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>[3] Data Transmission</td>
   <td>[4] Transmission Media</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>[5] Signal Encoding Techniques</td>
   <td>[6] Digital Data Communication Techniques</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is due to mixing css id and class to hide and display. Use id or class for both to be consistent. Use something like `.t1 { display: none;}` and `.show { display: block;} and `<tr class="t1">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.

For table elements however you need to use another property called `visibility`. If you notice you also need to include the `#t1 id` as .show by itself won't override the `#t1 style`:

## CSS

```
#t1{
  visibility: collapse;
}
#t1.show{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that **ID** have prevalence over **CLASS**. You can replace your t1's id with a t1's class.

```js
var t1 = document.querySelector(".t1");
function TogTop(){
     if (!t1.classList.contains("show")){
        t1.classList.add("show");
    }else{
        t1.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

```css
.t1{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
   <td>[1] Data Communications, Data Networking, and the Internet <button onclick="TogTop()">Topics</button></td>
  <td>[2] Protocol Architecture, TCP/IP, and the Internet-Based Applications</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="t1" class="t1">
            <td colspan="2">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>[3] Data Transmission</td>
           <td>[4] Transmission Media</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[5] Signal Encoding Techniques</td>
            <td>[6] Digital Data Communication Techniques</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change css:

```html
.show{
    display: block !important;
}
```

this example:

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
function TogTop(){
     if (t1.classList.contains("show") == false){
        t1.classList.add("show");
    }else{
        t1.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

```css
#t1{
    display: none;
}
.show{
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
   <td>[1] Data Communications, Data Networking, and the Internet <button onclick="TogTop()">Topics</button></td>
  <td>[2] Protocol Architecture, TCP/IP, and the Internet-Based Applications</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="t1">
            <td colspan="2">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>[3] Data Transmission</td>
           <td>[4] Transmission Media</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[5] Signal Encoding Techniques</td>
            <td>[6] Digital Data Communication Techniques</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```